# Unable to install Sample OE schema in Pluggable DB in Oracle 19c

Tags: database, oracle, database-schema, oracle19c

I am a newbie and learning. I have installed oracle 19c EE and my pluggable db is orclpdb. Though I have succesfully installed the HR and SH sample schemas in orclpdb but failed to isntall the OE schema(order Entry). I have downloaded the sample schema zip file from Github and followed the instruction from https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC001.I changed the **SUB__CWD** with C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/ in oe_main.sql. Excerpts is as below:-
DEFINE vscript = C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_&vrs

@&vscript &vrs &pass &pass_sys &connect_string

--

-- call script to load OE objects

--

DEFINE vscript = C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_&vrs

@&vscript &vrs &data_path &log_path &pass

--

-- call script for post-load operations on OE

--

DEFINE vscript = C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_&vrs

@&vscript &vrs

--

-- OC subschema

--

@C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/order_entry/oc_main

--

-- statistics

--

@C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_analz

But I am getting error. Sharing a portion of the entire log:-

```
Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter session set container = orclpdb;

Session altered.

SQL> show con_name;

CON_NAME
------------------------------
ORCLPDB
SQL> startup
ORA-65019: pluggable database ORCLPDB already open


SQL> @?/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_main.sql

specify password for OE as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: pass

specify default tablespeace for OE as parameter 2:
Enter value for 2: USERS

specify temporary tablespace for OE as parameter 3:
Enter value for 3: TEMP

specify password for HR as parameter 4:
Enter value for 4: hr   

specify password for SYS as parameter 5:
Enter value for 5: Admin1234

specify directory path for the data files as parameter 6:
Enter value for 6: C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/order_entry/

writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 7:
Enter value for 7: C:/Oracle/db_home/demo/schema/log/

specify version as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: v3

specify connect string as parameter 9:
Enter value for 9: localhost:1521/orclpdb

DROP USER oe CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'OE' does not exist


old   1: CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY &pass
new   1: CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY pass

User created.

old   1: ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
new   1: ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS

User altered.

old   1: ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
new   1: ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP

User altered.


Grant succeeded.

Grant succeeded.

Grant succeeded.

Grant succeeded.

Grant succeeded.

Connected.

Grant succeeded.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
Connected.

Session altered.


Session altered.


specify Sample Schema version as parameter 1:

specify password for OE as parameter 2:

PROMPT password for SYS as parameter 3:

specify connect string as parameter 4:

CREATE TYPE cust_address_typ
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02304: invalid object identifier literal


CREATE TYPE phone_list_typ
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02304: invalid object identifier literal


SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/ccus_v3.sql"
   ON customers (customer_id)
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


ALTER TABLE customers
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/cwhs_v3.sql"
ON warehouses (warehouse_id)
   *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


ALTER TABLE warehouses
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



Table created.

Index created.

Index created.

Table altered.

Trigger created.

SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/cord_v3.sql"
ON orders (order_id)
   *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


ALTER TABLE orders
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



Table created.

Index created.

Table altered.

Table created.

Table altered.

Table created.

Index created.

Table altered.

Table created.


Table altered.

ALTER TABLE orders
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


ALTER TABLE orders
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


ALTER TABLE warehouses
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


ALTER TABLE customers
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


      REFERENCES warehouses (warehouse_id)
                 *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



Table altered.

      REFERENCES orders(order_id)
                 *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


Table altered.

Table altered.

Synonym created.

Synonym created.

Synonym created.

Synonym created.


Sequence created.

SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/coe_xml.sql"

Commit complete.


specify Sample Schema version as parameter 1:

specify location for data and control files as parameter 2:

specify location for log files as parameter 3:

specify password for oe as parameter 4:

Setting FEEDBACK OFF for inserts

SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/oe_p_pi.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/oe_p_pd.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/pwhs_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/pcus_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/pord_v3.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/oe_p_itm.sql"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/oe_p_inv.sql"
Setting FEEDBACK ON
```

I have changed each instance of "**SUB__CWD**" with the destination path. Still facing the problem.The same way I was able to install the HR and SH schema. Please help.

Comment: There are legacy Oracle Import script files in order entry directory  which needs path adjusted to current directory(exactly 5 files and 131 lines).If you have ubuntu wsl installed or any bash tools like git bash,cygwin use [perl](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas) command(check  subsection 2.3 from the link)  to change directory path or use notepad++  or any other tools

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed and it works. Though some of the views are missing. Well still works. :)